# Как выдать роль при использовании команды discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

У меня не получается это сделать, перепробовал куча способов, на некоторых показывалось это в консоли при использовании команды

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: message is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def give_role(ctx: commands.Context):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: а куда айди роли сувать?)

Comment: В следующий раз пишите конкретнее, исправил

Comment: спасибо вам, всё получилось!)